# How do we get already initialize value in another checkbox

Tags: angularjs

***here is my html code***;

I want to fetch value of first checkbox which is already initialize and the by selecting another checkbox i can get value of first one

```
<div class="widget-body" style="display: block;">
  <div class="widget-main">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table">

        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>item</th>
            <th>issued</th>
            <th>received</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody ng-repeat="emp in nodueitassets">
          <tr>
            <td>{{emp}}</td>
            <td>
              <input type="checkbox" value="{{emp}}" ng-model="checked" ng-init="checked=true" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="checkbox">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

***JS CONTROLLER***

Comment: you are every init every checkbox . because it is in loop ...

Comment: can u send me controller code how to fetch this checkbox value

Comment: Check this link and try to implement it that way.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D